# How to do nested numbered lists?

Tags: support

How do I create nested numbered lists? I want something that looks sort of like:

> 1. yada yada for item 1
> 2. yada yada for item 2
>
> > a. yada yada for item 2a
> >
> > b. yada yada for item 2b
>
> 3. yada yada for item 3

---

Edit. Per orthocresol's comment...

1. yada yada for item 1
2. yada yada for item 2

   1. yada yada for item 2a
   2. yada yada for item 2b
3. yada yada for item 3

Comment: Put more spaces before the numbers in the nested list, but I'm not sure that lists work at all with a. b. c. -- afaik only with 1. 2. 3.

Comment: Some references: [How to write nested numbered lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85474/how-to-write-nested-numbered-lists); [CommonMark tutorial](https://commonmark.org/help/tutorial/10-nestedLists.html).